# parse http response header from wget

Tags: http, parsing, header, response, wget

Im trying to extract a line from wget's result but having trouble with it.
This is my wget call:

```
$ wget -SO- -T 1 -t 1 http://myurl.com:15000/myhtml.html
```

Output:

```
--18:24:12--  http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx:15000/myhtml.html
           => `-'
Resolving xxx.xxxx.xxxx... xxx.xxxx.xxxx
Connecting to xxx.xxxx.xxxx|xxx.xxxx.xxxx|:15000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2008 23:24:12 GMT
  Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
  Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
  Location: https://xxx.xxxx.xxxx/siteminderagent/...
  Content-Length: 508
  Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: https://xxx.xxxx.xxxx//siteminderagent/...
--18:24:13--  https://xxx.xxxx.xxxx/siteminderagent/...
           => `-'
Resolving xxx.xxxx.xxxx... failed: Name or service not known.
```

if I do this:

```
$ wget -SO- -T 1 -t 1 http://myurl.com:15000/myhtml.html | egrep -i "302" <br/>
```

It doesnt return me the line that contains the string. I just want to check if the site or siteminder is up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The output of wget you are looking for is written on stderr. You must redirect it:

```
$ wget -SO- -T 1 -t 1 http://myurl.com:15000/myhtml.html 2>&1 | egrep -i "302"
```

Answer (score 10):

`wget` prints the headers to stderr, not to stdout.  You can redirect stderr to stdout as follows:

```
wget -SO- -T 1 -t 1 http://myurl.com:15000/myhtml.html 2>&1 | egrep -i "302"
```

The "2>&1" part says to redirect ('>') file descriptor 2 (stderr) to file descriptor 1 (stdout).

Comment: Good additional detail to @Piotr's answer.

Answer (score 2):

A bit enhanced version of already provided solution

> wget -SO- -T 1 -t 1 http://myurl.com:15000/myhtml.html 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -c 302

`2>&1 >/dev/null` will trim off unneeded output. This way egrep will parse only wget`s stderr, what eliminates possibility to catch strings containing 302 from stdout (where html file itself outputted + download proces bar with resulting bytes count e.t.c.) :)

`egrep -c` counts number of matched strings instead of simply output them. Enough to know how much strings egrep matched.

Answer (score 2):

wget --server-response http://www.amazon.de/xyz 2>&1 | awk '/^  HTTP/{print $2}'

Answer (score 1):

Just to explicate a bit.  The `-S` switch in the original question is shorthand for `--server-response`.

Also, I know the OP specified `wget`, but `curl` is similar and defaults to STDOUT .

```
curl --head --silent $yourURL
```

or

```
curl -I -s $yourURL
```

The `--silent` switch is only needed for `grep`-ability: (`-s` turns off progress % meter)

Comment: some servers don't respond to a head request

Answer (score 0):

I found this question trying to scrape response codes to large lists of URLs after finding `curl` very slow (5+s per request).

Previously, I was using this:

`curl -o /dev/null -I --silent --head --write-out %{http_code} https://example.com`

Building off Piotr and Adam's answers, I came up with this:

`wget -Sq -T 1 -t 1 --no-check-certificate --spider https://example.com 2>&1 | egrep 'HTTP/1.1 ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4`

This has a few bugs e.g. redirects return `302 200`, but overall is greased lightning in comparison.